# Is the surface of the Earth expanding in GR?

Tags: general-relativity

If freely-falling frames are the local inertial frames according to GR, then is the surface of earth "really" expanding outward at a every point on the surface, locally? What does this mean?

Comment: I think this is a fascinating question and it was one of the high points in my (physics) life when I realised I knew the answer. See the linked question where I discuss it in some detail.

Comment: Great qn!!  I thought the same too.

Comment: @XcoderX was it you voted to reopen? While I think it's a great question (and I upvoted it) it is definitely a duplicate of the question I linked.

Comment: @JohnRennie After going through all that, not able to understand half the math, what I understand is that the answer to my question is "Yes" ??

Comment: Sort of. If you're standing on the surface of the Earth then relative to an observer at infinity you are accelerating in time - sort of. It's the movement along the time axis that causes the gravitational force.

Comment: @JohnRennie  no it wasn’t me

Comment: @JohnRennie It's kinda weird that while stationary on Earth, I am accelerating "in time", while acceleration itself is related to change in positions _over_ time

Comment: Wrong! *Coordinate acceleration* is change in position with time, but coordinate acceleration is a three vector and not covariant. The acceleration in GR is [four acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-acceleration). This includes a term $dt/d\tau$, where $\tau$ is proper time.

Comment: @JohnRennie Ok, I was just saying.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be critical. I think this is a really good question and I upvoted you for spotting that the question existed, even though it is a question that has been asked and answered before. The problem is that it isn't possible to give more than a caricature of an answer unless you're willing to get down and dirty with the maths.

Comment: @JohnRennie So, the surface of the Earth is accelerated "in time" with respect to an inertial frame. But, the freely-falling frames are accelerated "in space" with respect to the Earth. How does that work?